# Convert a PySpark Dataframe Column to a Python List depending on the value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe "dfClean" with 2 columns:

```
+---+-----+
|som| ano |
+---+-----+
| 1 |  1  |
| 2 |  0  |
| 3 |  1  |
| 4 |  1  |
```

I need to create a Python list with those values in "som" that have 1 in the column "ano" on the same row.
So expected output is:
`pyLst = [1,3,4]`

In Pandas I have used:
`pyLst = dfClean.som[dfClean.ano == 1].tolist()`

How can I do this in PySpark or in Scala and what additional libraries do I need to import?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the filter first, then select the `som` column, collect the rows into a Python list, and get the element from each row:

```
pyLst = [r[0] for r in df.filter(df.ano == 1).select('som').collect()]

print(pyLst)
[1, 3, 4]
```

Another way is to convert to a pandas dataframe first, then call `.tolist()` as you did in your question:

```
pyLst = df.filter(df.ano == 1).select('som').toPandas()['som'].tolist()
```

You can also use the RDD API:

```
pyLst = df.filter(df.ano == 1).select('som').rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter and then collect the required column only as rdd and later convert to list. You can use list comprehension to do this.

It will look like this,

```
lst = [row[0] for row in sdf.filter("ano = 1").select('som').collect()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `groupby` and use spark's `collect_list` function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F   
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 1), ], ['som', 'ano'])
pyLst = df.groupby('ano').agg(F.collect_list('som').alias('pyLst')).where('ano = 1').collect()[0]['pyLst']
```